# Web UI control to be passed to a class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

Hey all i have this code here:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "showNotifier", ";$(function() {showNotifier(3000,'#cf5050','" & msg & "');});", True)
```

That i am wanting to place inside a class file like so:

```
Public Class topMsgNotifyer
   Public Shared Sub show(ByVal delay As Integer, ByVal colorOfBox As String, ByVal message As String)
      Try
          ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(String), "showNotifier", ";$(function() {showNotifier(" & delay & ",'" & colorOfBox & "','" & message & "');});", True)
      Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
   End Sub
End Class
```

And of course it has a problem with Me.Page inside the class file.

I can get the current page name by doing this:

```
Dim pageName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Path)
```

How can i correct this when calling that class sub from a asp.net page instead of calling it on the page itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the Page object to your show() method, however, a better approach would be to create a class that is a BasePage class, in which your pages inherit from.  In that class, make you show() method.  Consequently, every page that inherits this BasePage will have access to that method, and Me.Page will be available.

Passing the Page object:

```
Public Class topMsgNotifyer
   Public Shared Sub show(ByVal delay As Integer, ByVal colorOfBox As String, ByVal message As String, ByVal page as System.Web.UI.Page)
      Try
          ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, GetType(String), "showNotifier", ";$(function() {showNotifier(" & delay & ",'" & colorOfBox & "','" & message & "');});", True)
      Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
   End Sub
End Class
```

call it:

```
topMsgNotifyer.show(30, "Red", "You did something wrong", Me.Page)
```

Comment: How do i pass the page object?

Comment: I do not recommend that. I can show you passing the page and creating a base class?

Answer (score 1):

These kind of thing are usualy done in a user control which will have access to the page.

An other option you be to pass the Page variable to the function as a parameter.
Or have your function return a String instead with the script, and then call RegisterClientScriptBlock like you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Why is people saying not to pass an instance of a page? I see nothing wrong with this:

```
public static void clientOnLoadScript(System.Web.UI.Page instance, string script, bool addScriptTag = false)
{ 
    string toWrite = "$(window).load(function () { \n" + script + "\n });";

    instance.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(instance.GetType(),"OnLoad", toWrite,addScriptTag);
}
```

then just call the function:

```
clientOnLoadScript(this,"script",true);
```

This works for me. Good luck.

Comment: Page is a pretty big object.  It doesn't need passed.